# Не работает рассылка через $mail = Mail::factory('smtp');

Tags: email, smtp

Не работает рассылка через

```
$mail = Mail::factory('smtp');
$mail->send($to, $headers, $body);
```

Корректно отрабатывает, если заменить на `$mail = Mail::factory('mail')`

Comment: в качестве рассылки установлен и настроен. функция mail() php работает корректно, меня интересует именно smtp

Answer (score 0):

Судя из **[доков](https://php.ru/pear/package.mail.mail.factory.html)**

```
object &factory ( string $backend , array $params = array() )
```

Создает экземпляр почтовой программы, где

> string $backend - the name of the backend "mail","smtp", "sendmail"

Так что у вас бэкенд является типом `mail`

> Mail supports three types of backends (Mail поддерживает три типа бэкенда):
>
> **mail**
>
> Sends a mail using PHPs build-in mail()-function.
>
> **sendmail**
>
> Sends a mail using a sendmail program.
>
> **smtp**
>
> Sends a mail directly connecting to a smtp server.

Comment: у меня используется метод smtp.  по нему же проблема, письма не доходят, и написал же mail работает

Comment: @lolka что еще за метод? и причем тут какой-то метод? Сервер должен быть настроен на отправку через сокеты, а не какие-то там методы ...... также, возможно при smtp надо указывать хост (адрес или доменное имя сервера, на котором запущен почтовый транспортый агент, готовый принимать почту) и порт, `Mail::factory('smtp', array('host' => 'localhost', 'port' => 25));` к примеру

Comment: пробовал с параметрами, тоже не работает, повторюсь на сервере все настроено правильно ,через веб интерфейс - почтовый сервер смтп отправляется норм. а тут таким способом не отправляется

Comment: пробовал с параметрами, тоже не работает, повторюсь на сервере все настроено правильно ,через веб интерфейс - почтовый сервер смтп отправляется норм. а тут таким способом не отправляется. Вот передаваемые параметы $mailer_params['auth'] = true;
$mailer_params['debug'] = true;
$mailer_params['username'] = 'username@mail.domain.ru';
$mailer_params['password'] = 'password';
$mailer_params['port'] = '25';
$mailer_params['host'] = 'mail.domain.ru'; вот параметы